# Meteor.JS YouTube Auth and Data

Tags: youtube, meteor

So what I've got now is hosted at http://exonia.meteor.com/ -- I've got Google authentication all working, and I've got the two YouTube scopes I want added and working as well.  However, when I try to access any of the data from the YouTube API in the Users Collection, the only thing I have is the full name of the user, from their YouTube Profile.

How can I access the YouTube data?

EDIT: I've now deployed to the domain mentioned above, my apologies--was deploying to a custom domain and forgot about that one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If everything is going as intended, you should have access to the Youtube information in the server. If that's the case, then you need to tell Meteor to also expose that information to the client by [publishing](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_publish) it (only basic info is published by default).

For instance, if you want to add some extra fields to the user object from the data you've received from Youtube, do something like this:

```
Meteor.publish("extra_fields", function() {
  return Meteor.users.find(
    {_id: this.userId},
    {fields: {fieldYouWantToPublish: 1}} // 1 indicates you want to include that field
  );
});
```

Meteor will automatically merge the requested fields into the user object for you. Don't forget to subscribe to it!

Comment: Would I still have to do this even with autopublish added?

Comment: Yes, autopublish only autopublishes username and profile fields: `If the autopublish package is installed, the username and profile fields for all users are published to all clients.` (from the [meteor docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_users))